# Why do we have to create tmpNext in this java method?

Tags: java, methods, reference, nodes

The method inserts a new Node object after the current one. I don't understand why we do not simply have in the method `this.nextNodeRef = nodeLoc;` all alone. Why is it import to conserve the original reference to the Node in a temporary variable? Why do we store it after the current Node `nodeLoc` in the nextNodeRef variable (another IntNode)?

```java
public void insertAfter(IntNode nodeLoc) {
      IntNode tmpNext;

      tmpNext = this.nextNodeRef;
      this.nextNodeRef = nodeLoc;
      nodeLoc.nextNodeRef = tmpNext;
   }
```

Comment: if you do `this.nextNodeRef = nodeLoc;`, what happens to the original "next node" of `this`? Are you just going to throw it in the trash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that any given `IntNode` object 'knows' what the next item in the list is.

Originally, you have, say:

```
A[5] -> B
B[8] -> C
C[12] -> D
D[2] -> E
```

(i.e., the first node is called 'A', has value 5, and knows that the next node is B. The B object has value 8, and knows that the next node is C, and so on).

Now you want to insert Z after B. The `IntNode` object representing Z has a blank `nextNodeRef`.

To do this, you want `B` to no longer point at `C`, but to point at Z.

However, if that's all you do, the list is now `A, B, Z` and it ends there. If you want `A, B, Z, C, D, E`, then `Z`'s `nextNodeRef` needs to be pointing at C.

Where do you get C from?

Well, that *used to be* what B was pointing at.

That's what the code does: "Saves" C, updates B to point at Z, then updates Z to point at the thing you saved, which is C. Then, you get:

```
A -> B -> Z -> C -> D -> E
```

Comment: thank you! I was only thinking of the case where you add at the end of the list. That seemed redundant in my head. I now understand.